# Сочетания клавиш в консоли, ввод-вывод

Tags: c++, windows, input, io, hotkeys

Учу С++. Хочу разобраться, как работает ввод-вывод в консоли.
Уже понял, что если вводишь в `cin` слова через пробел/табуляцию, он считывает их через этот данный разделитель и выводит в `cout`. К примеру, ввожу `"hello man"`, - выводит `"helloman"`. Это нормально, все ясно.
Также я узнал, что <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> останавливает процесс и означает символ конца файлы при считывании. Нажимаю <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (перед этим не ввожу символы) и процесс завершается.

**Вопрос 1**: почему, если я ввожу, к примеру `"hello ^Z"` (`^Z` я именно ввел сочетанием клавиш, а не вручную сначала ^, потом Z), то сначала в потоке вывода появляется `hello`, а за ним ничего не появляется, только если нажму enter, выводится вопросительный знак в квадратике! (что это вообще такое?)

**Вопрос 2**: Если потом `cin` считывает символы через разделители, почему тогда он не считал сначала `hello`, потом ^Z и в соответствии с командой не завершил процесс, считав символ конца файла, как его называют в книге Страуструп.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
int main() {
    
    
    string current;
    
    while(cin>>current){
        
        cout << current;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это особенности работы `cmd.exe`.

`cmd.exe` отправляет текст в поток ввода построчно, и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> закрывает поток ввода только если до него не были введены другие символы.
В этом можно убедиться переписав программу следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::string s;
  while (std::cin >> s)
    for (int b : s)
      std::cout << std::hex << b << ' ';
}
```

Если что-то было введено до `^Z`, то он интерпретируется как `\x1a` ([*символ замены*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)), и всё что введено в этой строке далее - игнорируется:

```
> test.exe
1^Z23
4
31 1a 34
```

При этом по умолчанию `std::istream` не считает `\1a` разделителем слов.

Если до `^Z` ничего не вводить, то поток закрывается, а последующие символы в строке игнорируются:

```
> test.exe
123
31 32 33 ^Z456

>
```

Comment: Хорошо, но почему тогда в windows это сочетание клавиш мало того, что не сразу появляется, если его написать через пробел с другим словом в потоке вывода, как я и писал `hello hello` => hellohello, но
`hello ^Z` => hello (нажимаем enter) => вопросик в квадрате

Comment: вот именно, что он прочитал весь файл и как бы должен узнать о закрытии потока, дочитав до ^Z, но он не закрывает его, а продолжает принимать данные

Comment: я всего лишь использую сочетание `ctrl-z` и символ `^Z` сам появляется на экране

Comment: По-моему, для лучшего понимания примеров надо как-то разделить ввод и вывод. Цветом или просто в отдельные блоки.

Comment: @Abyx как это правильно сделать на SO я не знаю. Просто хотелось бы отделить строки ввода от строк вывода, а то они путаются сейчас.

Comment: Вот это другое дело. Спасибо большое.